# finding records with same foo but different boo

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to filter record with same `nickname` but has records with different `contactId`, but I couldn't.

```
SELECT
    nickname, contactId, COUNT(*)
FROM
    UserProfileContacts
GROUP BY
    nickname, contactId
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This is what I expect as result;

```
userId A | nickname B | contactId C
userId A | nickname B | contactId D
userId B | nickname C | contactId F
userId B | nickname C | contactId G
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: ms sql, management studio

Answer (score 1):

Remove contactid from `group by` and count the distinct occurrences of contactid per a given userid and nickname.

```
SELECT
    userid, nickname, COUNT(distinct contactId) contactid_count
FROM
    UserProfileContacts
GROUP BY
    userid, nickname
HAVING 
    COUNT(distinct contactId) > 1
```

To select the contactid just do,

```
SELECT u.userid,u.nickname,u.contactid 
FROM UserProfileContacts u
JOIN (
SELECT
    userid,nickname
FROM
    UserProfileContacts
GROUP BY
    userid,nickname
HAVING 
    COUNT(distinct contactId) > 1) t ON t.userid = u.userid AND t.nickname = u.nickname
```

Comment: this brings same contactIds, contactIds should be different, also can you add userId with nickname because some nicknames very common.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server,Use the below query with cte and count() over()..

```
  ;WITH cte_1
  AS
    ( SELECT *
         , count(contactid) over(partition by    userid,nickname order by userid,nickname) cnt
   FROM UserProfileContacts)
   SELECT DISTINCT userid,nickname,contactId
   FROM cte_1
   WHERE cnt>1
```